# how to connect my cordova app to an existing web server containing php files

Tags: php, web-services, cordova, xampp, ip

I'm new to working with real web servers 
I developed my Cordova app and used PHP files using XAMPP to provide web servers

but now I want to publish the app and I have a fully functional web server 
how can I access the PHP files (I already put in this web service) using the POST method (found in my index.js file in my Cordova app)?

I tried changing the URL in the ajax post request 
from http://localhost/config.php for example 
to [http://IP_OF_WEB_SERVER/config.php](http://IP_OF_WEB_SERVER)

but it's giving a connection timeout
how can I get this to work?
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very clear. You can't access your webserver from cordova, or you want to load a php file inside cordova?

The apache cordova doesn't support the usage of php, and another thing is that you can't use the localhost directly. You can use the `inappbrowser` plugin or ajax to fetch your contents from a remote web server.
In the first case with the plugin, you only need to specify the web address of your webserver that host your app .php files. With ajax instead you need to set some rule of the default content security policy that is shipped when a cordova app is build.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
i have my php files (that i use to access the database ) in the remote web server
and i am requesting these files from cordova using AJAX
but it isnt working
what is the correct way to do so

Comment: You need to write a middle page that will manage the ajax requests otherwise you can't do anything within your cordova app. This page will be responsable to accept the requests and extract data from your file that contain the database management logics. Here on Stackoverflow there are more examples on how to achieve this task.